# OpenERP How to make a button invisible when datetime field != date today

Tags: xml, odoo

In python, I have the following field:

```
'transaction_date': fields.datetime('Transaction Date')
```

In XML, I have the following:

```
<field
    name="transaction_date"
    readonly="True"
    />

<button
    name="set_void"
    string="Void"
    type="object"
    icon="gtk-cancel"
    groups="mymodule.mygroup"
    attrs="{'invisible':[('transaction_date','!=', datetime.now())]}"
    />
```

The attrs code above doesn't currently work but what I want to do is:
be able to show the "Void" button only when the transaction_date field's date value = Today. Is that possible?

Comment: Which version of OpenERP are you using?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **v7**, then try this **attrs**:

`attrs="{'invisible':[('transaction_date','!=',__import__('time').strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%M:%%S'))]}"`

---

If you are using **v6** or **v6.1**, then try this **attrs**:

`attrs="{'invisible':[('transaction_date','!=',time.strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H:%%M:%%S'))]}"`

I would like to suggest you that you should use`fields.date` instead of `fields.datetime` because your field will not be visible in **datetime** format because whenever you will select **date** & **time**, seconds will not be match.

If you will use **fields.date** then use `time.strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d')` in **attrs**.

Thank you.

Comment: Arya - thanks man. Oh, I thought there is a way to somehow format my fields.datetime transaction_date on XML to get only the date. I really need to record the time for the transaction_date